# Increasing the distance from the wall of my pull up bar

Tags: walls, basement, mounting

I have the following chin up bar that is too close to the wall when using my new set of rings.

[image]

What is the best way to increase the distance from the wall? Can I simply add two vertical 2x4 (at each end) in between the chin up bar and existing horizontal 2x4?

Comment: "Best way" depends on how much more distance you want. Is 1.5 inches enough? By the way, you have some mighty fine-looking floor joists visible overhead. They'd carry the weight of a chin-up bar at any arbitrary distance away from the wall..

Comment: I think 1.5 in would be enough. Can you elaborate on the floor joists method? What would a setup like that look like? I'm intrigued now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For just 1.5 inch more space off the wall, sure, another layer of 2x4 could work fine. It's not necessary to pull the existing horizontal boards off the wall; you could just build up another layer in front of those. Thinking about how the forces might be in play I guess orienting the second layer vertically could be a bit better.

If you wanted to hang the arrangement from the ceiling.. what if you rotate the brackets so that they attach to the bottom side of the I-joists? If that puts the bar a little too low you could install some 2x blocking between the webs of the floor joists and fix the brackets to that instead.

On the other hand, if brackets mounted to the I-joist flange puts the bar too high above the floor then you'd have to find a way to bring it down lower. Lots of strategies to do that.. some kind of lumber hanging down from the joists. Might be a patch of plywood fixed to the side of two floor joists, and a piece of 2x4 at the lower edge of the plywood to give a secure surface for mounting the pull-up bar brackets.

Comment: To confirm, you're referring to something like this? https://www.studbarpullup.com/2014/03/10/mounting-a-pull-up-bar-to-engineered-beams-tji-floor-joists-engineered-lumber/ Noting that the bottom of my joists measure 2 1/2 x 1 1/2... at first glance, this doesn't seem much to hold all that weight.

Comment: @TekiusFanatikus Yes, if the one you have now were rotated 90 degrees it would look about like the one in that link. The flange on the I-joist can carry quite a lot of weight -- though it looks thin, it is bonded to the vertical web of the joist and that's where the strength is. If your fingers and grip are up to the task, you could grab one of those flanges and hang from it. It'll easily carry your weight.

Comment: I will keep this in mind. TIL.